# Cheers to that!

Tags: expressions, idiomatic-language

I posted a question on another forum and there seemed to be different opinions on whether "cheers to that" was idiomatic. I believe I've heard it and seen it in moves in scenarios like this:

Two guys sit at a table in a bar, each with a beer in hand.

Guy #1: ...But I'm feeling a lot better now.

Guy #2: Well, cheers to that.

They drink.

Would it be natural/idiomatic to you?

Comment: I'd probably say ***Here's** to that!* as I raised my glass (inviting others to share the "toast"). As a Brit, I'm much more used to *Cheers **for** that* (thank you for that which you did for me), so the ***to*** version grates on me a bit. But there are [many written instances](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22cheers+to+that%22) (usually in the context of *drinking*, even if it's only a cup of tea! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's very common, at least in Canada and the US. It means something like, "Let's drink to that" or "I'd drink to that (if I had a drink)".

Here's [100+ video examples](https://youglish.com/pronounce/cheers%20to%20that/english?), including some famous YouTubers like Hank Green.